# Does this confirm that Young Griff may not be who he claims to be?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Given what we know for certain now in Game of Thrones TV series

> That Jon Snow is the Heir to the Throne and Aegon Targaryen/Young Griff is not appearing in the TV show in the final series.

Then does this confirm that

> Young Griff is an imposter and therefore his storyline is irrelavent?

Or is it more likely that the Books will go in a very different direction to the TV series in effect creating 2 timelines by combining 2 character's into 1 for the TV series (something that has been done many times throughout the Series).

Comment: This is in my opinion, opinion based. That being said. I think it's more than likely that they've ignored the character entirely in GoT and that in ASoIaF Young Griff will remain legitimate. Why would so much time be invested in this character for him not to be legitimate. Also, doesn't he have the classic silvery hair of the Targaryens?

Comment: GRRM is not going to confirm it, you must be aware of that. Many people speculated that fAegon is fake when GoT showrunners decided to cut his arc, making it look like it won't have any impact on the larger picture long before the revelation. This POB and speculative. It may or may not confirm that. Show was navigating into a different direction already. They didn't need fAegon in the story they were telling, which is different from the story Martin is telling and wants to tell

Comment: Aegon/Young Griff could be Blackfyre pretender. Why else would second sons be with him?

Comment: My theory is that Young Griff's plotline has partly been absorbed by Daenerys. Tyrion/Varys are with her (show) instead of him (books) and for their plot it didn't matter if their armies are Unsullied, Dothraki, or the Golden Company, so far. Even the presence of her dragons in Westeros is not strictly needed (yet) - in the books, the NK presumably uses the horn of Idontknowhisname (left out in the show, so they brought the dragons to fill this gap) to bring down the Wall, and the raid party was an obvious ass pull anyways. See? It's still all speculation, and fAegon could still be real.

Comment: @jo1storm Second Sons were with Daenerys until Siege of Meereen. It's the Golden Company who is backing fAegon

Comment: You're correct. Golden Company was created by a Blackfyre: The Golden Company is a company of sellswords founded by the Great Bastard, Aegor Rivers, known as "Bittersteel".

Comment: Asha Greyjoy is absent from the TV show (even if there is a "Yara Greyjoy"), does that mean Asha is not who she claims to be ? of course, no. It's just a modification (Asha seems to close to Osha), to not confuse the public. Cut of Young Griff arc is another modification. Just look at how rushed the events of season 7 were, do you really think there is air time left to introduce a potentially major character ?

Answer (score 4):

### 1. The books and show have diverged.

The books and show plot have contradicted eachother several times already. Although the general narrative seems to be the same, the details are not.

You can't make a decision about the future book plot based on the TV show, as there is no basis for you to assume that the show is being faithful to the books.

Young Griff doesn't even appear or get mentioned in the show, so there is no reason to think that Jon's real name (which has currently **only** happened in **the show**) is inherently also making decisions about Young Griff's storyline in the books.

### 2. Young Griff is (claimed to be) Rhaegar's first son called Aegon. Jon is Rhaegar's second son, also called Aegon.

I think you're confusing the two Aegons. Notice that when I use "Aegon1", I mean the son of Rhaegar and Elia, and "Aegon2" refers to the son of Rhaegar and Lyanna, who we of course know as Jon Snow.

Even if you assume the books and show to agree on these facts, I'm not sure how you're assuming Jon's name reveal to have an impact on Young Griff's alleged true identity.
For the continuation of the answer, let's assume that Young Griff **exists** in the show universe, but simply has not had any screen time (because if you assume he doesn't exist, then answer 1. is the answer)

Aegon1 is assumed to be dead. However, Varys and Illyrio *claim* that they have actually spirited the boy away to Essos, and have future plans for him. Regardless, everyone at least **thinks** that Aegon1 is dead.

Aegon1 is already (assumed to be) dead by the time Jon (Aegon2) is born. Although we don't know exactly *why* Lyanna chose to name him Aegon2, there are a few good reasons:

- She named him after Aegon1 who had already died (as far as Lyanna knows), to honor his memory.
- Rhaegar was really into the prophecy of Azor Ahai. He was naming his children after Aegon the Conqueror and his sister-wives Rhaenys and Visenya. Rhaegar already had named his children Aegon1 and Rhaenys. It stands to reason that if Jon had been a girl, that they would've named her Visenya. But Jon turns out to be a boy, and since the other Aegon is no longer alive (assumedly), they choose to reuse the name in order to "retry" fulfilling the prophecy of Azor Ahai.

*Note that Rhaegar had already died by the time Jon was born. It's uncertain whether Lyanna chose to reuse the name Aegon herself, or whether she and Rhaegar had agreed on the name. Regardless, Lyanna using a Targaryen name clearly shows that even if she made the decision herself, she was still trying to honor Rhaegar's intentions. She must have been aware of why Rhaegar really wants to have a son named Aegon, or at the very least **that** he wants a son named Aegon, even if she doesn't know why that is the case.*

Regardless of **why** Jon is named Aegon2, his name has nothing to do with whether or not Young Griff is Aegon1.

### 3. Regardless of Jon's name, Young Griff could already have been an impostor.

This answer is based off of [Alt Shift X's video about Varys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M_hhVg9XUE&feature=youtu.be).

Note that this answer has nothing to do with Jon at all (so I'll keep it brief, as it is arguably off-topic). It just shows the point that Young Griff could already have been an impostor, and his hidden identity of Aegon1 Targaryen is merely a ruse in order to get him on the Iron Throne.

A quick rundown of the theory:

- Young Griff is actually a Blackfyre (= Targaryen bastard lineage)
- Varys and Illyrio are currently hiding him under the name Young Griff.
- Varys and Illyrio are trying to make people **believe** that Young Griff is in fact Aegon1, and thus the rightful ruler of Westeros over Danaerys.

This would mean that the fake identity of Young Griff will later be "revealed" with another fake identity of Aegon1 Targaryen, while the child is in reality a Blackfyre.